# jQuery hide div not working in success

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to put jQuery for hiding div after success and search all over the web but no luck.

Please anyone guide me.

```
success: function(json) {
 $('#order_popup_button_'+order_id).removeClass('disabled');
 $('#order_popup_button_'+order_id).val('<?php echo $button_change_order_status; ?>');
  if (json['error']) {
    alert(json['error']);
  }
  if (json['success']) {
    //change colors in background:
    $('#order-status-'+order_id).css('background-color', order_status_background_color[new_order_status_id]);
    $('#order-status-'+order_id).css('color', order_status_text_color[new_order_status_id]);
    $('#order-status-'+order_id).html(new_order_status_name);

    //This part is not working (it's hiding but not as expected)
    $(".go-btn").on('click',function() {
      var v = $('#item1 option:selected').val();
      if (v == 114) {
        $('#testhide'+order_id).hide();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Just use the debugger to see if the flow is correct or not first (if the code actually go inside), then see if the value you expect and the variable is correct or not. Or better if you can make a jfiddle example

Comment: what do you mean with `hiding but not as expected`?

Comment: check what is giving the output for `'#testhide'+order_id` and validate with your element id.